# Git, why was my master branch affected?

Tags: git

I was working on a master branch. Had a new idea, so I went with:

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

Did some changes on the new branch and then switched back to the master. All the changes I did on new branch were applied to master. What should I do to prevent that?

Comment: That sounds unlikely. How did you switch back to the `master` branch? Also, did you actually `add` and `commit` the changes? Only **tracked** files will get changed on `git checkout`.

Comment: This is a common misconception of new Git users. The changes that were not committed do not belong to any branch. When you switch the branch, Git preserves the changes in the working tree and the staged files, if they don't conflict with the changes introduced by the new branch.

Comment: Switched back with `git checkout master`. I did not `add`, nor `commit` on either branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't `add` or `commit` the new files they are untracked and outside of your git repo. They only exist on the filesystem. You can delete all of them using `git clean -f -d` to restore the clean state of your repo.

Comment: So, what I should do, was `commit` changes on master? Would it then be unaffected by any new branches? What I did on a new branch was actually useless and wanted it deleted anyway.

Comment: If you have a new idea you probably either want to `git commit` or `git stash` the local changes for later or `git reset` or `git clean` them to discard current work. It's really up to you.

Answer (score 3):

When you do not commit changes to the new branch, the changes are cached and accessible via the parent branch (`master` in this case)

To prevent this, you should always `git add [FILE]` and `git commit` before switching to the parent branch.
In case you do switch before committing, simply switch back to the new branch, add the changed file(s) and commit

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't add or commit anything :

```
# switch to your new branch
git checkout new_branch_name

# confirm that your changes are still there :
git status

# commit on your new branch
git add ...
git commit ...

# go back to master
git checkout master
```